# mysqli fails to set session timezone on connection. Remain UTC. On RDS mysql instance

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-web-services, mysqli, rds

I'm on AWS using a mysql RDS instance version 5.5.40-log.

I'm using PHP 5.5.12 and connecting with mysqli.

I've been trying to track down an sql bug in a script and found that despite setting the timezone on the connection to 'Australia/Sydney' it remains in UTC and the sql call to now() returns the wrong time. So my results are out.

Below is a simplified call I'm making which, despite the TZ change makes no difference to the result of now().

```
$db = new mysqli("axxxx.chxxxxx.ap-soxxxxt-2.rds.amazonaws.com", "xxxx", "xxxxx", "xxxx");
$db->query("SET timezone = 'Australia/Sydney'");

$res = $db->query("SELECT @@session.time_zone tz, now() now");


for ($row_no = $res->num_rows - 1; $row_no >= 0; $row_no--) {
$res->data_seek($row_no);
$row = $res->fetch_assoc();
echo " id = " . $row['tz'] . "\n";
echo " now = " . $row['now'] . "\n";
}
```

This results in:

id = UTC
 now = 2015-06-07 01:46:05

Actual time here is 11:46.

If i log onto the mysql database through mysqlworkbench and run the same code **it works**. So the problem seems to be that the session TZ is not getting set on the php mysqli connection and I'm not sure why?

I can see the mysql.time_zone_name table is populated similar to:

Africa/Abidjan 1
Africa/Abidjan 2
...etc

***EDIT***

I create a new direct session in mysqlworkbench:

```
SELECT @@global.time_zone, @@session.time_zone; -- UTC UTC
SELECT now(); -- 2015-06-07 21:55:54 <<incorrect time

SET time_zone = 'Australia/Sydney';

SELECT @@global.time_zone, @@session.time_zone; -- UTC Australia/Sydney
SELECT now(); -- 2015-06-08 07:55:03 <<correct time
```

I used @@session.time_zone in my example as this is the variable updated when setting the time_zone system setting directly.

Replicating the same thing via mysqli and php does **not** update this and the now() function does not return the correct date. Hence something is missing.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set time zone of mysql?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/930900/how-to-set-time-zone-of-mysql)

Answer (score 1):

You're setting `timezone` variable, but selecting `@@session.time_zone`. The right way is to set `@@session.time_zone` variable:

```
mysql> SET @@session.time_zone='Australia/Sydney';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> SELECT @@session.time_zone;
+---------------------+
| @@session.time_zone |
+---------------------+
| Australia/Sydney    |
+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: The underlying fail was ignoring the return value of `$db->query()` which should have made the problem obvious.

Comment: I updated my question to clarify the example I used with @@session.time_zone.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot good point, I was using this from another example found on stackoverflow. I'll test the return value